# Confused on which selector should apply some css properties

Tags: css, list, selector

Have a simple question:

properties like `list-style-position` should be added in `ul` selector, `li` or both?

Comment: this is one for google mate, but on the `ul` would be best practice.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, if you found anything related on Google, would be awesome.

Comment: For questions like this, consult the official W3C reference. In the case of list styles, [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#list-style). It says list styles are inherited, so the answer is, you can assign them either to the li, or to the ul, where the list items will inherit them from.

Comment: And it's OK to be confused. Which styles are inherited and which ones are not, seems to be an arbitrary choice without rhyme or reason.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister - will check that. Thanks god it's OK to be confused ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property `list-style-position` specifies if the `list-items` markers should appear `inside` or `outside` the content flow. The default value for it is `outside`.

You should use it on `ul` or a `wrapper div` that contains items, because its value gets inherited. Here's a simple example taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp).

```css
ul.a {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<p>The following list has list-style-position: inside:</p>

<ul class="a">
  <li>Earl Grey Tea - A fine black tea</li>
  <li>Jasmine Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
  <li>Honeybush Tea - A super fruity delight tea</li>
</ul>
```

***Further reading***: [W3C: list-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#list-style), [MDN: list-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position), [CSS tricks: list-style](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/)

Comment: Thanks! So, using this in a custom reset css, I can add all list properties to * and it should be fine. Anyway, thinking out loud now, seems better to just use ul.

Comment: @SHAMAN if you are using a custom reset for your CSS make sure you are loading it before your main css and that you are not giving `list-style:none;` on `ul` items. Anyhow, glad to help.